# Load store in grid within a modal window

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, store

I have a widget with two grids.

When selected a row of the first grid is done the load of the second grid 
according to the id_note sent on request.

If the grids are, for example, in a layout hbox, it works well.

However, when the second grid is within a modal window, the load of the store failed.

What is failing in my code?

```
(...)
},{
xtype: 'actioncolumn',
text:'Notes',
minWidth: 40,
flex:0.30,
align:'center',
items: [{
        icon: 'resources/images/loadWin.png',
        tooltip: 'show window',
        handler: function(grid, record, item, index, e, eOpts){               
            var selectRow = grid.getSelectionModel().select(record);
            var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getLastSelected(record);
            var id_note= selection.get('id_note');

            var win = Ext.widget('popupWindow', {
                animateTarget : item,
            }).show();

            var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gridItemId')[0]; //grid within win
            var store = grid.getStore();

            store.proxy.extraParams = {
                'id_note': id_note
            },

            //Right up to this point

            store.load(); //**PROBLEM HERE**
        }

    }
(...)
```

Comment: Not enough details. How exactly does the store fail to load? What do you see? Does it make a call to the server? Is there an error message? What Ext JS version are you using?

Comment: I am using EXTJS 5.1. The store.load generate an error; Uncaught Error: Can not modify ext-store-empty. About request: success: {success: true}, total: "4", but store rootProperty returns null.  What is strange, is if the grids are, for example, in a layout hbox, it works well. just does not load if the second grid is within a window. Thanks Drake.

Comment: Does the grid within window have a unique `itemId`? Are you sure that `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gridItemId')[0]` returns the grid within window and not any other grid?

Comment: Yes. I checked that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was to obtain the grid store reference in this case ( grid within window created dynamically).

I got the store reference with StoreManager (storeId) and now works well.

```
//var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gridItemId')[0];
//var store = grid.getStore();

var store = Ext.getStore('storeId');
```

Thanks again Drake.

Comment: That's why it's important to post a test case. Nobody would have been able to answer that because you didn't post the relevant code.